My if statement `${{env.mytrue}} == 0` doesn't seem to work in GitHub Actions conditional
I have the following job ...
foo:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  env:
    mytrue: 1
  steps:
    - name: Conditional Test
      if: ${{env.mytrue}} == 0
      run: |
        exit 1;

When I have DEBUG logging on, I can even see this evaluated as false..
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Conditional Test'
##[debug]Evaluating: (success() && format('{0} == 0', env.mytrue))
##[debug]Evaluating And:
##[debug]..Evaluating success:
##[debug]..=> true
##[debug]..Evaluating format:
##[debug]....Evaluating String:
##[debug]....=> '{0} == 0'
##[debug]....Evaluating Index:
##[debug]......Evaluating env:
##[debug]......=> Object
##[debug]......Evaluating String:
##[debug]......=> 'mytrue'
##[debug]....=> '1'
##[debug]..=> '1 == 0'
##[debug]=> '1 == 0'
##[debug]Expanded: (true && '1 == 0')
##[debug]Result: '1 == 0'
##[debug]Starting: Conditional Test
##[debug]Loading inputs
##[debug]Loading env
Run exit 1;

However, why if the condition is evaluating to false is the run,
##[debug]..=> '1 == 0'
##[debug]=> '1 == 0'
##[debug]Expanded: (true && '1 == 0')
##[debug]Result: '1 == 0'

Why is the run block executing?

This is because ${{ }} creates a GitHub context. And from the notes in the documentation

Contexts are usually denoted using the dollar sign and curly braces, as ${{ context.property }}. In an if conditional, the ${{ and }} are optional, but if you use them they must enclose the entire comparison statement, as shown above.

So the right answer here is not to use Contexts...
foo:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  env:
    mytrue: 1
  steps:
    - name: Conditional Test
      if: env.mytrue == 0
      run: |
        exit 1;

Explanation
What you're seeing is because otherwise under the hood the Context executes in a .format()
format('{0} == 0', env.mytrue))

Which evaluates to a string..
##[debug]....Evaluating String:
##[debug]....=> '{0} == 0'

The string '1 == 0' is true in Bash..
bash -c 'if [ "1 == 0" ]; then echo TRUE; fi;'

And the implementation depends on that string being reduced to "0" or "1". If you instead use ${{env.mytrue == 0}} it will evaluate as such.
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Conditional Test'
##[debug]Evaluating: (success() && (env.mytrue == 0))
##[debug]Evaluating And:
##[debug]..Evaluating success:
##[debug]..=> true
##[debug]..Evaluating Equal:
##[debug]....Evaluating Index:
##[debug]......Evaluating env:
##[debug]......=> Object
##[debug]......Evaluating String:
##[debug]......=> 'mytrue'
##[debug]....=> '1'
##[debug]....Evaluating Number:
##[debug]....=> 0
##[debug]..=> false
##[debug]=> false
##[debug]Expanded: (true && ('1' == 0))
##[debug]Result: false

You'll see now there is no format, and you have this
##[debug]..Evaluating success:
##[debug]..=> true
##[debug]..Evaluating Equal:

